# How to fix missing HTML<open> & <close> tags in middle of HTML string

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, string

I have to validate HTML string in my project,

I have an html with :

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Test 2</li>        
    </ol>
    <li>Test 1</li>
</ul>
```

Required Output is :

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
</ul>
```

In HTML code `</ul>` and `<ul>` tags are missing.  Now in this case how to Search where are the missing tag and how to insert appropriate ending tag and beginning tags in proper places.

I tried HTML agility pack and Tidy library, but I couldn't find better solution for this issue.

Comment: You want to validate it with code? VS can validate HTML code in editor.

Comment: I get this HTML code as a out put from Richtext Editor most of times HTML code is validated by editor but, when user incorrect bulletining and numbering with indentation editor will not validate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using any DOM manipulation library, you will need to create a ruleset describing which elements can be children of a `<ul>` element. Iterate over all of its children, and when you find a child (`<ol>`) that's not allowed, move all subsequent children, including the `<ol>` child, to the parent of the `<ul>` element, placing it at the index of the `<ul>` element + 1.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do this approach.